# How to send custom links to individual school/orgs for a Qualtrics survey which can then be used multiple times in that school/org

Tags: qualtrics

We're running a survey for school students. We want to capture the school details of each student who answers, but we're worried that students will mistype or use junk data in the school name field.

We would like to send a custom link to each school, which the school can then distribute amongst the students. Any student following this link will have the school ID automatically assigned to them.

I can see how you assign customer details to a unique link

[image: adding personal links]

But each link only works once, you can't get a school using it for multiple students. We don't want to create personal links for individiual students

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do this from personal links, the best way is to set up a range of email links then distribute those separately:

First, go to Distributions -> Emails -> Compose Email

Then make a new contact list with the schools you want (you can do this separately and load it in), and your email as the email, this will allow you to collect the links to then send separately

Under Advanced Options at the bottom of the email form, select Multiple Completes.

In the contents of the email, add the "External Data Reference" field using the {A} menu i.e. the name of the school given above

You can then adjust the text of the email to be the school name, so you it's obvious which school each link is for

Then adjust the sending time to send immediately

Send the emails, and you'll have custom links for each school.